# Using two System.Threading.Timers

Tags: c#, timer

I need to use 2 timers in two different Threads, but it seems to don't work.

I've tried on a console and I have this result : http://puu.sh/810Ki.png.

That's the code :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(Start1);
        thread1.Start();

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(Start2);
        thread2.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Start1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " Begin System.Threading.Timer1.");

        Timer timerThread = new Timer(TimerConnectionThread_Finished1, null, 10000, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private static void Start2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " Begin System.Threading.Timer2.");

        Timer timerThread2 = new Timer(TimerConnectionThread_Finished2, null, 10000, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private static void TimerConnectionThread_Finished1(object stateInfo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " End System.Threading.Timer1.");
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " Begin System.Threading.Timer1.");
        Timer timerThread = new Timer(TimerConnectionThread_Finished1, null, 10000, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private static void TimerConnectionThread_Finished2(object stateInfo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " End System.Threading.Timer2.");
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " Begin System.Threading.Timer2.");
        Timer timerThread = new Timer(TimerConnectionThread_Finished2, null, 10000, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
```

We can see that Timer1 et Timer2 toggle. What should I do ? Use System.Timers.Time ? Code my own timer ?

Thanks,

Veriditas :)

Comment: This is entirely normal.  Quite unclear what else you expected or why this is a problem.

Comment: Congratulations, you've found a race condition.  Whenever you have a program with more than 1 thread, you probably have lots of them.  If it's important that operations from different threads happen in a well defined order, or to ensure certain sequences are logically atomic", you need to use some form of synchronization to define what that behavior is.

Comment: The console can only output one thing at a time. What else do you expect to happen?

Comment: Well, I'm coding a soft which use a thread for the socket connection with the server, and another to check the user licence every minute. The problem is that when the socket connection stop unexpectly, the soft reconnect 10 minuts later. But I've notted that sometimes, the reconnection work but the licence check doesn't, or the licence check work but the reconnection doesn't work. And it's only a timer problem.
And @CathalMF, it's not a output problem. If it is, we should see "End timer 1 Begin timer 1 End timer 2 Begin timer 2 End timer 1 Begin timer 1 End timer 2..."

Comment: Indeed, it seems I was wrong, we can use 2 timers in the same time. I've changed the interval of the second timer (23000) and I have this result : http://puu.sh/81aVA.png